# domparser remove node not working

Tags: javascript

Below  is the code snippet:

```
var tmpl = "<book><auth> </auth> <price> </price> </book>";
var bkTmpl  = parser.parseFromString(tmpl,'text/xml');
var bk = bkTmpl.cloneNode();
```

And i am removing the child 'price' as below. Both Try1 & Try2 is not working

Try1:

```
var bkprice = tmpl.getElementsByTagName('price')[0];
bkTmpl .documentElement.removeChild(bkprice);
```

Try2

```
var bkprice = tmpl.getElementsByTagName('price');
bkTmpl.documentElement.removeChild(bkprice);
```

For Try1 it throws error =>
"Node was not found"

For Try2 it give =>
Could not convert JavaS...DOMElement.removeChild]

Google few option but i see only removeChild to remove it. However when I use document.getElementById  & use removeChild function it does not complain. Only reason I am using js variable (var tmpl) as I wanted to use snippet of xml as part of javascript that can be changed in future as ajax call & hence do not want to be part of HTML. I saw on firebug for both Try1 & Try2 "price" element is populating

Comment: rectified typo it is tmpl not tw... I am able to resolve for now using jquery $(bkprice).remove() & not sure how it does it now but will dig into it.. however I would like to do without jquery as it is xml if could do it with plain old method it would nice

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace this line:

```
var bkprice = tmpl.getElementsByTagName('price')[0];
bkTmpl .documentElement.removeChild(bkprice);
```

by

```
var bkprice = bkTmpl.getElementsByTagName('price')[0];
bkTmpl .documentElement.removeChild(bkprice);
```

`getElementByTagName` is a method of bkTmpl  and not tmpl.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DWCpd/)